# Images are not displaying properly in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm somehow new in Laravel App development. I'm working on a project and everything is working fine, but in a section I need to display images like a gallery collections of images and I'm  accessing images from a hosted server with a stored image link in Database table.

There is a problem in displaying images some of the images are displaying and some of them are not displaying when I'm  refreshing the page this time some other images are not displaying and some of them do. I think there may be problem on how I'm accessing images from database or may be client side scripting languages.

Images are not completely loaded from server and the image field displays only a not found image icon instead of image. With each refresh of page (re loading the page) some new images are finding the same problem and some of previous images which are not displayed before this time displaying properly . I wonder why this happens? please somebody help me.

`Note:` Project hosted in a production server.

This is the rout value of images when I'm accessing them.

```
 Route::get('productimage/{file_name}', function($filename){ $path =
 storage_path('app').'/productimage/'.$filename; $image =
 File::get($path); $mime = File::mimeType($path); return
 Response::make($image, 200)->header('Content-Type', $mime); });
```

this is how I'm accessing images in views

```
 <img src="{{asset('productimage/'.$row->image)}}" class="img-class"/>
```

this is a screen shoot from images in view 
[image]

this is a screen shoot of images after page refreshed

[image]

Comment: do u inspect element ??? did u see that image link is ok???

Comment: where  your images are located???

Comment: Check if the URL in the image stored has the same type of slash

Comment: The path is not correct for the image.... Its for File Not Found.

Comment: images are stored in storage directory and that rout value in the top show the directory.
Mister   #Borm

Comment: yea all paths are correct and if i refresh again the page those images are showing not found this time will display and will found image but this time other images which ware displayed before this time will not display

Comment: I've encountered this many times before. I'm not sure if this is an issue with laravel or not, but the **only** way I've been able to resolve this, is implementing a javascript library for lazy loading images on the web page: http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/. I never encountered any issues after that. I would create an issue on laravel/framework. But this issue is so hard to debug that I'm not sure if it's server / PHP related. One other option may be caching the image with laravel before returning the response which may work.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem too. In my case it was because my web server(nginx) had ngx_http_limit_req_module enabled in conf (limit_req zone=one burst=5;) file which refuses connection if more than 5 request were made in a row (when page is loaded for the first time it sends http request for each items loaded for the page, including image files, so in my case it was showing not more than 5 images).